# Logwatch - Being probed by own network router?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, ubuntu-server, logwatch

I have been having some fun messing around with Apache running on an Ubuntu Server. It is set up as a global web server and shares some files that I can access anywhere. I am also using it to connect to my music and play it via my Android phone when away from my house. It also houses shares that are only visible to my local network.

I set logwatch up a few weeks ago and have logs sent to me every morning via email. Every now and then I am seeing this in my logs (or something very similar).

```
Attempts to use known hacks by 1 hosts were logged 3 time(s) from:
   <Routers local IP Address>: 3 Time(s)
```

Logwatch shows no successful attempts were made and I am pretty sure I am not really being hacked. But what would cause my routers local IP address to show up in logwatch as a threat?

Is it secretly out to ruin me `O-o`?

Just some other tidbits about the network:

1. My Router hides my home network behind a NAT
2. I do develop on Android and make connections to it via the emulator in Eclipse as well as from my phone.
3. My phone as well as home PCs connect to the web share to stream music and download files (globally and locally)

I can't seem to pinpoint exactly what is causing this..

- Bad android code?
- The fact that the server shares locally and globally?
- Accessed from a cell network?

***EDIT: More about my architecture***

My home network is behind my routers NAT (router local IP is .1). I have a laptop and a desktop both who have static IPs. My desktop can connect wireless and wired. I also have a Wii that connects when it needs to go online etc. The below is the table from my router showing what has connected.

```
.2    <MAC ADDRESS>   expired (This is my Desktops Wireless Conn.)
.3    <MAC ADDRESS>   Forever (This is my laptop)
.4    <MAC ADDRESS>   Forever (This is my Desktop Wired Conn.)
.8    <MAC ADDRESS>   Forever (This is my Wii)
.5    <MAC ADDRESS>   Forever (This is my phone)
```

I matched all of the MAC addresses to a device in my home.

I have also looked at the logs the router records (to long to post) but the only IPs there are that of devices in my house.

***Edit: More Router info***

- [EnGenius ESR9850](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833168050)
- NAT is enabled
- Router firewall is enabled
- The router supplies two different SSIDs(but this shouldn't be causing
  a problem)
- The router has port forwarding and forwards port 80 to a higher
  number port and forwards it to the server at .6)
- The router is set to only allow IPs from .2 - .10 to make a connection.
- The router and each SSID are password protected (all different passwords)

***Edit: Received another hack attempt***

Today I received the following

```
Attempts to use known hacks by 1 hosts were logged 1 time(s) from:
X.X.X.X: times(1)

A total of 1 sites probed the server
X.X.X.X
```

The IP listed is clearly a global IP address and not that of my router.

From the answers below it seemed that I would only be seeing the routers IP as the "hacker". How come in this case it shows a global IP.

**Note: This global IP is not the global IP of my NAT nor is it the global IP of my smart phone.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your server is open to the Internet it is also open to attacks, which is what I believe is happening. Your router's *external* IP address is in an address segment of the Internet that is being scanned by one or more infected computers that are using known exploits.

The attacks on your computer seem to come from the router, because the router stands between you and the Internet :

[image]

The attacks are coming over TCP/UDP ports that you have forwarded in the router to your computer,
such that any connection attempt on these opened ports to your router's external IP address,
is actually transformed into a connection attempt by the router to your computer,
the router acting in this case as an agent for the external attacker.

As you are being attacked, it would be a good idea to upgrade your security.

See the [LQ Security references](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/security-references-45261/) for an overwhelming list of possible measures for hardening your Linux box. Of special interest for you is the SSH section at the end.

There are many other articles on the Internet on this subject. Some that would be useful:

[10 Tips to Secure Your Apache Web Server on UNIX / Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/apache-hardening/)
[Security Tips - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links I have already used them. I should have mentioned I have hardened the server before I posted the question. But why would the attacker show up as my local IP address (the router) and not anohter global IP address? Also this is the only data that is showing regarding the "hack attempt". +1 for responding! Thanks!

Comment: For your phone to connect with your computer via Internet, you must have forwarded a port, which opened it to attack from the Internet. Your computer has the impression that it's coming from the router, because the router's doing NAT means that it is handling 2 connections: to the ISP using your external IP, and to your computer using its own internal IP, and transferring the data back and forth from one to the other. So Internet connections arrive to your computer on the opened port with the router's IP.

Comment: ... Which also means that products such as Fail2Ban are useless for you. Whatever blacklisting there is to do has to be done in the router.

Comment: Yes I am forwarding the port. When i look at the IPs that have made a connection to the router the only IPs present are ones from my home PCs, and the one that is linked with my phone. Could my phone  for some reason be considered bad to the router?

Comment: Could you include some more info about your architecture and the IPs that you see. All I really have are guesses.

Comment: Edited to add more info

Comment: Need more info about which IP is attacking you and on which port, what are the opened ports etc.

Comment: The only info in logwatch is what was stated in the question. It just says my routers ip (.1) attempted a known hack X amount of times. There is no info except that. I have upped the sensitivity of logwatch a few days after i posted the question, but I have not been "attacked" again. I will post any more info if something shows up. If it was another computer somewhere wouldn't its MAC be listed within the table I posted?

Comment: The MAC wouldn't be listed anywhere except in the router, since the exterior computer connects to your router, never directly to your computer. See for example [this NAT article](http://www.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm).

Comment: Yes that table was from my router. The MAC of no other machine/device except stuff I own is listed in the router. So this would mean something one of my devices is doing to something to set of an attack or a false positive?

Comment: No. I counsel reading carefully the above-linked [NAT article](http://www.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm). [This article](http://www.9tut.com/network-address-translation-nat-tutorial) will also help. I believe that the attack is coming from outside your network and from a device that is not in the MAC device list (since it is not in your home network). The router is just the pipe through which the attack arrives from the Internet.

Comment: The table is unpopulated until something makes a connection. For example my phone. Its not inside the router but once it connects to the server (inside the network) its MAC is registered in that table. Wouldn't another outside device do the same thing? Going to read the links thanks again!...Then again unless the phone only registered in the table when I connected to wifi otherwise it never would have registered? Like i said going to read the links :)

Comment: I edited and will award the bounty if you can make sense of this for me. Today I received an entry that a known hack was attempted 1 time from X.X.X.X. The IP listed is a global IP, not the routers IP. Why would it show up this time as global but other outside attacks would show up as the routers ip?

Comment: Could you please give the values of X.X.X.X and your router's external IP and its make?

Comment: Port forwarding works differently for inbound and outbound and this is further complicated by the protocol. Normally, however, port-forwarding only changes the destination IP, not the source IP. So, depending on the type/protocol of the attack, you will either see the real global IP of the attacker or your router's internal IP. Your [router's manual](http://www.engeniustech.com/resources/ESR9850_User_manual.pdf) also has both "port mapping" and "Port Forwarding", and frankly I don't think the writer understood the difference (so I don't too).

Comment: ...This also depends on the router and how close to the standard the firmware was implemented. Maybe a good explanation of the standard can be found in [another router's manual](http://documentation.netgear.com/wnr834b/enu/202-10171-01/WNR834B_UM-07-02.html).

Comment: Thanks, so all in all something somewhere is just doing a simple scan hack or something, and its not something internally that I am doing to set it off? Since its only 1-3 attempts once in a while and no sign of a successful attack it does not seem to be anything to worry about. The best I can do is to block those IPs and see what else I can do to harden the server then?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can also try to harden the router's firewall settings and make port forwarding as restrictive as possible.

Comment: Thank you, I had seen some of the links you posted before but will dig around for some more. Thanks for explaining it all, it's easier to harden the system when you know exactly what is going on. I am going to let this question sit for a while incase other want to reward you more rep, then I will give you the bounty. Thanks again for all the help.